# Quartus: VHDL error process

Tags: vhdl

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity top is 
port ( b,a: in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
         selU: in std_logic_vector  (1 downto 0);
         sel: in std_logic;
         selTop: in std_logic;
         salmux: out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
         result: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0));
end;

architecture behavioral of top is
    
process (selTop)
begin
    if selTop = '1' then
        entity work.uniarit(behavioral) port map (b, a, sel, result);
    else
        entity work.unilogic_mux(behavioral) port map (a, b, selU, salmux);
    end if; 
end process;
end architecture;
```

`uniarit` y `unilogic_mux` son otros programas

el problema es con `if selTop` o `process`, no estoy muy seguro, pero recibo los siguientes errores al compilar:

```
near text "process"; expecting "begin" or a declaration statement

near text "port"; expecting "(", or "'", or "."

near text ";"; expecting "<="
```

`selTop` es un switch para correr `uniarit` o `unilogic_mux`

¿alguien sabe porque recibo estos errores?

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente se deba a que omitiste algunas palabras en la sintaxis al realizar el programa, por lo tanto el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity top is 
port ( b,a: in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
         selU: in std_logic_vector  (1 downto 0);
         sel: in std_logic;
         selTop: in std_logic;
         salmux: out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
         result: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0));
end top;

architecture behavioral of top is 
begin
process (selTop)
begin
    if selTop <= '1' then
        u1: entity work.uniarit(behavioral) port map (b, a, sel, result);
    else
        u2: entity work.unilogic_mux(behavioral) port map (a, b, selU, salmux);
    end if; 
end process;
end architecture behavioral;
```